# What does the telescope do in Curious Expedition?

Tags: the-curious-expedition

At the start of an expedition, I am able to buy a Telescope and a Sextant.  The Sextant has *Reveal Distance: +2*, which seems pretty straightforward.  The Telescope reads: *Extra Map Point Chance: +30%*.   I feel like I understand all of the words in that sentence independently, but not together.  Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Please don't use backticks for non-code related things. It makes things more difficult for screenreaders. I fixed it this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every location discovered you gain one map point. For 3 map points you gain one exploration point, which can be used to level up characters. With the telescope you have a random 30% chance that a location yields you two points instead of just one.

(Disclosure: I'm a dev on the game :)